# Slow login after installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, 14.04, login

I freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04. I already used Ubuntu before, and it the did not take any noticeable time to login. However, in Ubuntu 14.04, Unity seems to start slowly. First, I only see the cursor and the background like in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears), but after 8-12 seconds the launcher and the top bar show up (unlike the thread linked above). Booting is as fast as always (time between start and login manager), but the login time is really annoying.
The questions I red are about unity not showing up at all.

Comment: did you solve it? I can only use it (open applications etc) after waiting 20s...

Comment: Yeah the problem was gone eventually randomly magically... Sorry I can't help :(

Comment: must have been some update, I will see what happens here, I dont like much updating certain things as sometimes they used to break up..

Comment: Maybe you can try see if this happens on a live system too, and if it does, try update and then see if the problem is solved... (Or install on a mini partition).

Comment: good idea! I will download a new one thx!